# the image of a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G$ is any group and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $\phi\colon G \to G'$ is a homomorphism of $G$ **onto** $G'$, prove that the image of $N$  i.e., $\phi(N)$ is a normal subgroup of $G'$.

Comment: This was flagged as a duplicate of [Showing that if a subgroup is normal, it's homomorphic image is normal](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/219069), but that is about proof details, whereas this question is asking for a proof.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\phi(a)\phi(N) = \phi(aN) = \phi(Na) = \phi(N)\phi(a)$ for every $a \in G$.
Since $\phi$ is surjective, $\phi(N)$ is a normal subgroup of $G'$.

Comment: @Makoto, I am wondering what is the role that "phi is surjective" in this proof? Will the statement that "the image of a normal subgroup of G under homomorphism is still a normal subgroup of G' still be valid when phi is not surjective? I cannot recall if every homomorphism is surjective, and don't follow that why you say "since phi is surjective". Thank you.

Comment: @Lily Since $\phi$ is surjective, every element $x$ of $G'$ can be written as $x = \phi(a)$ for some $a \in G$.
Hence, by the above equation, $x\phi(N) = \phi(N)x$ for every $x \in G'$.
Therefore $\phi(N)$ is a normal subgroup of $G'$.

Comment: @Makoto, thank you so much for your clarification.   Just want to be more clear, is surjective a built-in property for homomorphism? I remember there's a property that "a homomorphism is 1-1 iff Kernel={identity element}". But I cannot recall if there's a similar condition for a homomorphism to be surjetive(onto)? Thank you!!

Comment: @Lily You're welcome. I don't know what you mean by "a built-in property".
In general, there's no such condition as Kernel = 1 for a homomorphism to be surjective. However, if we only consider abelian groups. Such a condition exists. Namely Cokernel = 0.

Comment: @Makoto, by the question itself, it only says phi is a homomorphism, didn't mention phi is surjective, I'm confused that why we can say phi is surjective in the proof? Thanks for your kindly help.  ps. Sorry, my question might be very stupid...>"<

Comment: @Lily No problem. The question says it is "onto". It means surjective.

Comment: @Makoto,OMG... I didn't see the original post carefully @_@ I'm so sorry..... so if it's without phi being onto, we cannot draw the same conclusion right?

Comment: @Lily You are right.

Comment: @Makoto, thanks so much for your patience. :)