# Image of a normal subgroup is also a normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

I am trying to prove the following statement.

Suppose we have groups $G$ and $H$. Let $\phi : G \to H$ be an onto homomorphism. If $N$
is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $\phi(N)$ is a subgroup of $H$, then $\phi(N) \triangleleft H$.

My attempt : Consider elements $g\in G$ and $n \in N$. Since $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, we have that $gng^{-1} \in N$. Then $\phi(gng^{-1}) \in \phi(N)$. Since $\phi$ is an homomorphism, it follows that $\phi(gng^{-1}) = \phi(g)\phi(n)\phi(g^{-1}) =\phi(g)\phi(n)\phi(g)^{-1} \in \phi(N)$
where $\phi(g) \in H$ and $\phi(n) \in \phi(N)$. Therefore $\phi(N) \triangleleft H$ as desired.

Is this a valid proof for the given statement?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the image of a normal subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233634/the-image-of-a-normal-subgroup)

Comment: Nevermind, I see that your question is a solution verification. (I have retracted my close-vote.) Your proof seems fine to me.

Comment: You should explicitly mention where you use the surjectivity of $\phi$.

Comment: You need to be more explicit about why it is a subgroup to start with, although this is easy: refer to the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Yes, the (very small) gap in your proof, easily filled as noted by @CAB, is that you haven't said how you know that the conjugate of $\phi(n)$ by every element of $H$ is back in $\phi(N)$.

Comment: What you need to prove is that $h^{-1}nh \in \phi(N)$ for every $h \in H$ and you should state that up front. You then need to use the fact that $\phi$ is onto to select a suitable $g$ to plug into your argument (namely a $g$ such that $\phi(g) = h$).

Comment: It seems to me as simple as seeing that $\phi(n)$ runs through all elements in $h$ by surjectivity. Why must more be written?

Comment: @DerekLuna I think you mean $\phi(g)$, not $\phi(n)$.  And I'd encourage it to be explicitly written because this seems to be an early course in the sequence, so as a matter of good proof-writing (in my opinion), gaps like this should be filled.