# Let ${\rm Hom}:G\to G'$ be a homomorphism. Prove that if $H\unlhd G$ then ${\rm Hom}(H)\unlhd G'$.

Tags: group-theory, self-learning, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Let ${\rm Hom}:G\to G'$ be a homomorphism. Prove that if $H\unlhd G$ then ${\rm Hom}(H)\unlhd G'$.

My current approach is to show that ${\rm Hom}(gHg^{-1}) = g'{\rm Hom}(H)g'^{-1}$ using the properties of homomorphisms and normal subgroups but it seems too simple for this to be correct.

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/219069/104041

Comment: Hom must be onto. Otherwise see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532094/the-image-of-normal-subgroups. If Hom is indeed onto, this is a duplicate of the above and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297105/the-image-of-normal-subgroup-is-also-normal-subgroup, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013797/proof-that-this-is-a-normal-subgroup, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233634/the-image-of-a-normal-subgroup.

Comment: Ugh. Please note that “Hom” already has a meaning in group theory, and it is *not* the name of a homomorphism. I would strongly advice against using it that way.

Comment: So does $G'$ . . .

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: consider any example of a non-normal subgroup $G$ of a group $G'$. The identity map $\varphi : G \hookrightarrow G'$ is a homomorphism. $H=G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, while $\varphi(H) = G$ is a non-normal subgroup of $G$ by assumption.

However, if the homomorphism is surjective, then the claim is true. To show $g' \text{Hom}(H) g'^{-1} = \text{Hom}(H)$ write $g'$ as the image of some element $g$ of $G$ and use your work.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not true.** Take any $H$ that is not a normal subgroup of a group $G$.

Then the inclusion of $H$ in $G$ is a group homomorphism and the image of $H$ is obviously not normal in $G$.

*This is however true if the homomorphism is supposed to be onto.*